# Geonames JSONP results not showing in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, typeahead

I started to give angularJS more attention today, and in my project I would need geonames.
I wanted to create something like jQuery UI's autocomplete with geonames [like this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp).

All is fine when I `console.log` it, I get back the results, but for some reason I can't place it to typeahead's dropdown list.

scope

```
$scope.cities = function(cityName)
{
    return $http.jsonp("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q="+cityName+"&maxRows=6").success(function(data){
        $.map(data.geonames, function(item)
        {
            return item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName;
        });
    });
};
```

input

```
<input type="text" class="span4" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)">
```

I am using [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for angular js and I tried based on that example but something is wrong, could please someone give me a hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.jsonp` performs requests asynchronously, so what you do in your success callback is lost.

You can use `$q.defer` or a watcher (but apparently the latter doesn't work properly with `typeahead`) to apply the values from the success callback:

```
$scope.cities = function(cityName) 
{
    var dfr = $q.defer();

    $http.jsonp("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q="+cityName+"&maxRows=6").success(function(data){
        dfr.resolve($.map(data.geonames, function(item)
        {
            return item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName;
        }));
    });

    return dfr.promise;
};
```

}

Comment: sorry for the silly question i was reading te docs but it does not yet get over my mind, tried your code getting these 2 errors 
Error: $q is not defined - 
Error: defer is not defined
im sure im doing something wrong, thanks for your reply by the way

Comment: @LeventeNagy `$q` and `$http` are angular's services. You inject it in the function the same you injectd `$http`. Read about the [depedency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).